# What does it mean "something wound"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've looked for the definition of the word "coil" in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coil) and the definition states:

> "**Coil** - A length of something wound in a joined sequence of
>   concentric rings."

My question is what does it mean "**something wound**"?

Is the word "**something**" an intransitive pronoun? I knew just about intransitive verbs but rather than intransitive pronouns. Anyway, I don't know such structure in English.

Comment: something that is wound -- that's what it means

Answer (score 1):

"Something" is just a noun here and the object of the preposition "of." It's being followed by a participle phrase that begins with the past participle of the verb "to wind," which is "wound."

The meaning is that a coil is a length of something (such as a length of wire or a length of rope) *that is* wound . . .

I believe there is no such thing as an "intransitive" pronoun. The linguistic concept of transitivity applies only to *verbs*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity_(grammar)